# Overriding ingress domains in helm?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Let's suppose I have the following values files with the content.

**values.yaml**

```yaml
env: ""

ingress:
  envGeneratedNames:
    enabled: false
  extraNames: []
```

**values-develop-1.yaml**

```yaml
env: develop-1

ingress:
  envGeneratedNames:
    enabled: true
```

**values-develop-2.yaml**

```yaml
env: develop-2

ingress:
  envGeneratedNames:
    enabled: true
```

**values-production.yaml**

```yaml
env: production

ingress:
  envGeneratedNames:
    enabled: true
  extraNames: 
    - app.com
```

If I use develop files **values-develop-1.yaml**,  **app.develop-1.com** will be generated which means app.{{ .Values.env.}}.com is used. The same for **values-develop-2.yaml**.

However, if I use **values-production.yaml**, **app.production.com** and **app.com** will be generated.

I think to use the following template.

```yaml
{{- define "ingress.extraNames" -}}  
{{- if .Values.ingress.extraNames-}}  
{{- .Values.ingress.extraNames-}}  
{{- else -}}  
{{- printf "app.%s.com".Values.env -}}  
{{- end -}}  
{{- end -}}
```

But I can't understand how to inject it into the following file. Pay attention that I need to have only one ingress file.

```yaml
{{ $values := .Values }}  
{{ $release := .Release }}  
{{- range $ingress := .Values.ingress.names }}  
---  
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1  
kind: Ingress  
metadata:  
name: {{ $release.Name }}-{{ replace "." "-" $ingress }}  
annotations:  
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"  
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"  
spec:  
tls:  
- hosts:  
- {{ $ingress | quote }}  
secretName: "{{ $ingress }}.tls"  
{{- end }}
```